# Migration a jmeter project from v3 to v5 : issue with soap request

Tags: http, soap, jmeter, request, http-post

i have a working project with jmeter 3.1 using soap request sampler :
[Project Jmeter with version 3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8aKD.png)

[Http header manager congig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onT1x.png)

i tried to figure out the same project with jmeter version 5 using http request like this :

[Project jmeter version5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Px1N.png)

but i receive always those 2 error :
[Error received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw6MG.png)

can you help on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is in your [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), but the system under test complains that you're not providing correct [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) which must be `text/xml`

I believe if you add this header at least this issue will go away.

Going forward you can just record your test from JMeter 3.x in JMeter 5.x and it will generate relevant HTTP Request samplers and HTTP Header Managers.

More information: [Testing REST\SOAP Web services](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420915-Testing-REST-SOAP-Web-services)

Comment: issue resolved by adding Content-Type : text/xml